# node.js error trying to install express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Im trying to install express through npm:

```
npm install express -g
```

but it doesnt want to work:(

System is Windows XP

npm-debug.log says :

```
3672 error Error: read ECONNRESET

3672 error     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)

3672 error     at TCP.onread (net.js:539:19)

3673 error If you need help, you may report this log at:

3673 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

3673 error or email it to:

3673 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

3674 error System Windows_NT 5.1.2600

3675 error command "E:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "E:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
cli.js" "install" "express" "-g"

3676 error cwd C:\DOCUME~1\Admin

3677 error node -v v0.10.2

3678 error npm -v 1.2.16

3679 error syscall read

3680 error code ECONNRESET

3681 error errno ECONNRESET

3682 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It looks like `npm` cannot reach its repository. Are you using a firewall or proxy which filters outgoing requests?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but on Windows 8 Pro. Odd enough, a friend of mine with the exact same setup has no problems whatsoever on the same network connection. It started happening after I upgraded to node 0.10. Just to make it clear, I'm not using a Firewall or a Proxy and I can open npmjs.org just fine.